# Messed up with ppa: restore package manager

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa

I was trying to read a Matrioska video, so I've added the followiong ppa:

```
ppa:strukturag/libde265
```

but it supports until ubuntu vivid, so I've modified the list.d file changing wily to vivid, then I've installed the package gstreamer-0.10, but I've got a system error since it tried to also install libde265, which would have overwritten the existing libde265 library from libde265-0 package.

Now I'm trying to restore all the changes made; I've tried purge-ppa, delete the keyring and remove the installed gstreamer0.10, but apt-get still allows me to select the libde-265 package (even if it returns an error since the ppa repository file is missing)
What could I do?

EDIT:

```
apt-cache policy libde265

libde265:
  Installato: (nessuno)
  Candidato:  (nessuno)
  Tabella versione:
     1.0.2-1ppa1~vivid1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

EDIT2: I'd like to get rid of this message:

```
sudo apt-get install libde265
[sudo] password di matteo: 
Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
Generazione albero delle dipendenze... Fatto
Il pacchetto libde265 non ha versioni disponibili, ma è nominato da un altro
pacchetto. Questo potrebbe indicare che il pacchetto è mancante, obsoleto
oppure è disponibile solo all'interno di un'altra sorgente

E: Il pacchetto "libde265" non ha candidati da installare
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy libde265`

Comment: And why do you think, that `apt-get` shows `libde265`?

Comment: because it is contained in the status file, isn't it?

Comment: Forget the status file. The package isn't installable and it's not installed.

Comment: Please check the edit, I'd like Ubuntu forgets the existence of the ppa related packages

Comment: `grep libde265 /var/lib/dpkg/status`

Comment: Package: libde265-0
    Source: libde265
     libde265 is an open source implementation of the H.265 video codec.
    Homepage: https://github.com/strukturag/libde265
    Depends: libass5 (>= 0.10.2), [OMISSIS], zebrastripe
    Package: libde265
     libde265 is an open source implementation of the H.265 video codec. 
    Homepage: http://www.libde265.org